# i have already hide extension with help of .htaccess in php but i want to . If any user write extension in URL box provide error no page exist

Tags: php, mysql, .net

I have already hide extension with help of (.htaccess) in php. If any user write extension in URL box provide error no page exist.

for eg---> `index.php note exist`

but ----> index exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

```
# RedirectMatch for urls with .php extension
RedirectMatch 404 ^(.+)\.php$

# RewriteRules for not files && not directoris to php files
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```